# How to clear the textbox without clear function with selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium

I have 2D array list which contains 275 elements. I want to retrieve the excel files which are consist this array list in it. every 25 list are in one array. So I should take 11 excel files after this program run. **My program **works**!** unfortunately It does not downloaded the correct excel files.

I think the problem is after it download the excel file it doesn't clear the text file correctly. maybe appended it. I don't know.

```
from turtle import clear
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
my_Turkey_list = [
"02071110","02071130","02071190","02071210","02071290","02071310","02071320","02071330","02071340","02071350","02071360","02071370","02071391",
"02071399","02071410","02071420","02071430","02071440","02071450","02071460","02071470","02071491","02071499","02072490","02072590"],["02072630",
"02072670","02072699","02072710","02072720","02072730","02072740","02072750","02072760","02072780","02072791","02072799","02074230","02074280",
"02074561","02074593","02075551","02076005","02076051","02076099","04021011","04021019","04021091","04021099","04051010"],["04051011","04051019",
"04051030","04051050","04051090","04052010","04052030","04052090","04059010","04059090","07141000","07141010","07141091","07141098","07141099",
"11043090","12021090","12022000","12023000","12024100","12024200","12030000","12040010","12040090","12051010"],["12051090","12059000","12060010",
"12060090","12060091","12060099","12071000","12071010","12071090","12073000","12073010","12073090","12074010","12074090","12075010","12075090",
"12076000","12076090","12077000","12079110","12079190","12079210","12079290","12079910","12079915"],["12079920","12079991","12079996","12079997",
"12079998","12081000","12089000","15010011","15010019","15010090","15011010","15011090","15012010","15012090","15019000","15020010","15020090",
"15021010","15021090","15029010","15029090","15030011","15030019","15030030","15030090"],["15041010","15041090","15041091","15041099","15042010",
"15042090","15043010","15043011","15043019","15043090","15050010","15050090","15060000","15071010","15071090","15079010","15079090","15081010",
"15081090","15089010","15089090","15091010","15091020","15091080","15091090"],["15099000","15100010","15100090","15111010","15111090","15119011",
"15119019","15119091","15119099","15121110","15121191","15121199","15121910","15121990","15121991","15121999","15122110","15122190","15122910",
"15122990","15131110","15131191","15131199","15131911","15131919"],["15131930","15131991","15131999","15132110","15132111","15132119","15132130",
"15132190","15132911","15132919","15132930","15132950","15132990","15132991","15132999","15141110","15141190","15141910","15141990","15149110",
"15149190","15149910","15149990","15151100","15151910"],["15151990","15152110","15152190","15152910","15152990","15153010","15153090","15154000",
"15155011","15155019","15155091","15155099","15156000","15159010","15159011","15159015","15159021","15159029","15159031","15159039","15159040",
"15159051","15159059","15159060","15159091"],["15159099","15161010","15161090","15162010","15162091","15162095","15162096","15162098","15162099",
"15171010","15171090","20081110","20081191","20081192","20081194","20081196","20081198","20081199","23012000","23031011","23031019","23031090",
"23040000","23050000","23061000"],["23062000","23063000","23064100","23064900","23065000","23066000","23067000","23069005","23069011","23069019",
"23069090","23069093","23099010","38260010","38260090","12010010","12010090","12011000","12019000","12021010","12072010","12072090","12072100",
"12072900","23033000"]


print("-------------------------------------")
Tur_Im_Start_Year = input(" Year like '20XX':")
print()
print("<< All months >>, January , February , March , April , May , June ")
print("July , August , September , October , November , December")
print()
Tur_Im_Start_Month = input(" Month Exactly Like above:")
print("-------------------------------------")

# driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Webdriver\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Webdrivers\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get('https://biruni.tuik.gov.tr/disticaretapp/menu_ing.zul')
time.sleep(2)
driver.maximize_window()
element = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH,value='//*[contains(text(), "Product/Product Groups-Partner Country")]')                                                                                                            
element.click()
time.sleep(2)
radio_element_ppc = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH,value='//*[contains(text(), "Product/Partner Country")]')
radio_element_ppc.click()
time.sleep(2)
radio_element_HarSys=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/'\
'div/div/table/tbody[1]/tr[14]/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/span/span[1]/input')
radio_element_HarSys.click()
time.sleep(1)
radio_element_HS8=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/'\
'div/table/tbody[1]/tr[15]/td/div/span/span[4]/input')
radio_element_HS8.click()
time.sleep(1)
Next_btn=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/div/table/'\
'tbody[1]/tr[17]/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/button')
Next_btn.click()
time.sleep(4)
Year_Radio=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[5]/'\
'td/div/div/table/tbody[1]/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/span/span[1]/label')
Year_Radio.click()
time.sleep(1)
ListBox_Year_Select = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH,value="//*[contains(text(),'{}')]".format(str(Tur_Im_Start_Year)))
ListBox_Year_Select.click()                                                                                                       
time.sleep(2)
Month_Radio=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/'\
'div/div/table/tbody[1]/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/span/span[2]/input')
Month_Radio.click()
time.sleep(2)
ListBox_Month_Select = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH,value="//*[contains(text(),'{}')]".format(Tur_Im_Start_Month))
ListBox_Month_Select.click()
time.sleep(2)
I_know_HS8_code_Radio=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[7]/'\
'td/div/div/table/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[11]/td/span/span[2]/label')
I_know_HS8_code_Radio.click()
time.sleep(2)


for i in range (len(my_Turkey_list)):
    # Loop for filling 25 Hs Code   
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[7]/td/'\
    'div/div/table/tbody[1]/tr[3]/td/div/input').clear()                  # for clearing the textbox to make it ready for new 25 Hs Code
    for j in range (25):
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[7]/td/'\
            'div/div/table/tbody[1]/tr[3]/td/div/input').send_keys(my_Turkey_list[i][j])
        if(j==24):
            break
        else:
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[7]/td/'\
            'div/div/table/tbody[1]/tr[3]/td/div/input').send_keys(",")
    time.sleep(2)
    Country_information_Radio=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/'\
    'tbody/tr[9]/td/div/div/table/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[11]/td/span/span[1]/label')
    Country_information_Radio.click()
    time.sleep(1)

    Country_All_Select = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH,value='//*[contains(text(), "<< All >>")]')
    Country_All_Select.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    #--------------------------------------------
    if i<1:             #because we don't want to uncheck the check box again
        
        Import_ChkBox=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[11]/td/div/div/table/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/span/label')
        Import_ChkBox.click()
        time.sleep(1)
        Value_Euro_ChkBox=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[11]/td/div/div/table/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/span/label')
        Value_Euro_ChkBox.click()
        time.sleep(1)
        Excel_Type_Radio=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[13]/'\
        'td/div/div/table/tbody[1]/tr/td[1]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/span/span[2]/input')
        Excel_Type_Radio.click()
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[17]/td/div/div[3]/table/'\
        'tbody[2]/tr/td[2]/div/button').click()
        time.sleep(8) 
    else:
        Excel_Type_Radio=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[13]/'\
                        'td/div/div/table/tbody[1]/tr/td[1]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/span/span[2]/input')
        Excel_Type_Radio.click()
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[17]/td/div/div[3]/table/'\
        'tbody[2]/tr/td[2]/div/button').click()
        time.sleep(8)
```

Comment: Are you trying to clear text file or textbox? You mentioned as textbox in title but text file in the query.

Comment: @– Anand Gautam. I just want to clear textbox. not by clear() function.

Comment: what about just sending space ? Or sending backspace ?

Comment: you could learn to use `for sublist in my_Turkey_list:`, and `for value from sublist[:24]:` without `if j == 24:` You could also assign to variable `textarea =  driver.find_element( ...)` and later use `textarea.clear()` and later `textatrea.send_keys()` - this would create cleaner code.

Comment: your code works correctly for me - it downloads correct files. I can't reproduce your problem. The only idea: `.clear()` may run JavaScript code which may need time to clear `textarea` and you may need `time.sleep()` to wait a little.